# Error connecting to xrdp server with Windows Desktop

Tags: raspbian, xrdp

I have RPi 2, Raspian Jessie 1-11-2017.

I can ping PI on my LAN.
I can SSH into Pi from a Windows 7 machine.
I have a user 'rob' who is in the 'adm' group.

It appears that I cannot attach an image of the errors I am getting.

When I attempt to connect with  rob  I get an error:

```
Connecting to sesman ip  127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info ......
xrdp_process_login_response:  login successful ......
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1:5910
error - problem connecting
```

It seems strange that it says I am connecting to 127.0.0.0 (me) but in a YouTube training video it shows the same thing, but the YouTube video is successful at connecting.

I thought that maybe the xrdp server was not running, but other posts on this site indicate that xrdp is always running.

Any help is MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; here are the links to the solution I found:

[error - problem connecting to Raspberry Pi 3 with xrdp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56413/error-problem-connecting-to-raspberry-pi-3-with-xrdp)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314336

Short answer: 
Remove: xrdp (you will add it again), vnc4server, and tightvncserver
(if not installed these will just be ignored)

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp vnc4server tightvncserver
```

Install: tightvncserver

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver -y
```

Install: xrdp (only after tightvnc has been installed)

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp -y
```