# Debuggin Visual C++ for Linux via RDP

Tags: raspbian, c++, rdp

I've got a Pi 2 running Raspbian, for which I'm writing an application in Visual Studio 2017 Community, in Visual C++ for Linux. If I connect a display to the Pi's HDMI port and run my program from Visual Studio (in debug mode), I can see the application running on the Raspbian desktop. However, if I RDP to the Pi (using Gabriel Staples' suggestions in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56758/64882) I don't see my application, just an empty Raspbian desktop.

I'm using the same user account both for debugging and the RDP session. It looks like RDP starts a new desktop session or something, but my knowledge of Linux is too limited. What am I missing here? Is there a way to get RDP to display the same desktop 'session' as the connected monitor?